# flash as3 - event listener for startDrag, stopDrag?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events, drag

I want to be able to differentiate whether a movie clip was dragged or clicked, and execute different functions accordingly. The problem is that startDrag is initiated by the MOUSE_DOWN and stopDrag by MOUSE_UP, and the CLICK event triggers every time. What I want to do is, in a conditional in the click event, say something like "if dragging == true { do something }"

I figured I could set a flag in the mouse_up or mouse_down function, but the problem is that mouse_down occurs at the same time as mouse click. I need to be able to set the flags in the actual stopDrag() function or something. I've seen a solution which involves setting a timeout - I'd like to avoid that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something I've had to deal with many a times.

What I do is create an additional CLICK listener on the capture phase (with a higher priority than anything else you're using),  then on that handler, if you know it was a drag you stop the propagation of the event - then it doesn't reach any of your other click handlers.

So in your case, if you're using startDrag (I use my own custom drag routine), you could do something like this:

```
function myFuntionThatStartsTheDrag() {
    myDragObject.startDrag();
    myDragObject.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,suppressClick,true,9999,true);
}

function suppressClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    e.stopPropagation();
}

function myFunctionThatStopsTheDrag() {
    myDragObject.stopDrag();
    myDragObject.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,suppressClick,true);
}
```

Comment: awesome - didn't know you could set priorities. Not sure if I understand the capture phases (the third argument of the event listener).

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS948100b6829bd5a67edfb831266c0b5fc6-8000.html

Answer (score 1):

Compare the x and y positions at the start of the drag vs. the x and y positions at the end of the drag. If the x and y positions at mouseUp are equal to the x and y positions on mouseDown, then you know it was a click - otherwise it was a drag. A very brief example:

```
var mouseDownX:int;
var mouseDownY:int;

var dragging:boolean;

//...

private function onMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void {
    mouseDownX = stage.mouseX;
    mouseDownY = stage.mouseY;
    //...
}

private function onMouseUp(event:MouseEvent):void {
    if(mouseDownX == stage.mouseX && mouseDownY == stage.mouseY) {
        dragging = false;
    } else {
        dragging = true;
    }

    if(dragging) {
        //...
    }
}
```

You can remove the click listener if you do it this way, and just handle everything in the mouseUp.

You may need to add some tolerance to treat mouseUp as clicks even if x and y are not exactly equal but off by a few pixels (as clicks aren't always perfect up and down to the pixel) but the above code should do for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dispatchEvent` to create your own custom listeners.

Use it like this:

```
dispatchEvent(new Event("customEvent"));
```

And you can call it like a normal event:

```
addEventListener("customEvent", eventFunction);
```